# Executing functions stored in a string

Tags: string, function, delphi, execution

Lets say that there is a function in my Delphi app:

`MsgBox`
and there is a string which has `MsgBox` in it.

I know what most of you are going to say is that its possible, but I think it is possible because I opened the compiled exe(compiled using delphi XE2) using a Resource Editor, and that resource editor was built for Delphi. In that, I could see *most* of the code I wrote, as I wrote it. So since the variables names, function names etc aren't changed during compile, there should a way to execute the functions from a string, but how? Any help will be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

What I want to do is to create a simple interpreter/scripting engine. And this is how its supposed to work:

There are two files, scr.txt and arg.txt

- scr.txt contains:

  ```
  msg_show
  0
  ```
- arg.txt contains:

  ```
  "Message"
  ```

And now let me explain what that 0 is:

- First, scr.txt's first line is function name
- second line tells that at which line its arguments are in the arg.txt, i.e 0 tells that "Message" is the argument for msg_show.

I hope my question is now clear.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186458/delphi-call-a-function-whose-name-is-stored-in-a-string

Comment: Yes it is posible to do so, but why on earth would you do that?

Comment: @JensBorrisholt, think script,soap services,names stored in databases etc.

Comment: @LURD you got a point. But I think I'll wait for nafees

Comment: I want to do that just to make a simple scripting engine.

Comment: Depends on the version and how much rtti support you have. You also need to know the functions signature. Why do you want to do this though. Perhaps there's a better way.

Comment: Ok, scripting engine needs compiler or interpreter.

Comment: Save you time and use an existing. Delphi Webscript fx https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I think I've already solved my problem! The answer is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186458/delphi-call-a-function-whose-name-is-stored-in-a-string) question's first answer.

**EDIT:**
But with that, as for a workaround of the problem mentioned in first comment, I have a *very* easy solution.
You don't need to pass *all* the arguments/parameters to it. Just take my example:
You have two files, as mentioned in the question. Now you need to execute the files. It is as simple as that:
read the first line of scr.txt
check if it's a function. If not, skip the line
If yes, read the next line which tells the index where it's arguments are in arg.txt
pass on the index(an integer) to the "Call" function.
Now to the function which has to be executed, it should know how many arguments it needs. i.e 2
Lets say that the function is "Sum(a,b : integer)".It needs 2 arguments
Now let the function read the two arguments from arg.txt.
And its done!
I hope it will help you all.
And I can get some rep :)

Comment: What happens if the string contains the name of a function that takes a different number of parameters? Or with different types? And by anyone's definition, a scripting engine will support more than function calls. It would support branching and looping, and the creation of functions. It would have some form of I/O.

Comment: Also bear in mind that allowing your users to call arbitrary functions in your program allows them scope to break your program. You need to sandbox the user's code. Carefully limit its scope.

Comment: Answer to comment1: I've already found a workaround for that number of parameters.

Comment: The answer contains no information. Link only answers are not useful to future visitors. Anyway, it sounds like you've already decided to go your own way here. Good luck!

Comment: This isn't helpful to anyone, not even you. In my opinion.

Comment: It is helpful to me at least, well then, what did _you_ tell? Create an interpreter? Well then, I told _how_ to create it!

Comment: Not really. What you have has such limited functionality as to be next to useless. Try dwscript for comparison.

Comment: Who in the world do you think is going to tolerate coding in this janky "scripting language" you've devised? It's terrible, and will serve only as a selling point for your competitors.

Comment: and I forgot to mention, its actually not a scripting language, what I meant to say was a script that the <i>interpreter</i> would understand, not humans. And I have a compiler that can convert an easier language into this.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make a simple scripting engine.

In order to execute arbitrary code stored as text, you need a compiler or an interpreter. Either you need to write one yourself, or embed one that already exists. Realistically, the latter option is your best option. There are a number available but in my view it's hard to look past [dwscript](https://code.google.com/p/dwscript/).